# Directly get the value of a defined command

Tags: macros, environment-variables

I defined a new comman or a definition which should store the value of my default font with:

```
\newcommand{\defaultfont}{\fontname\font}
```

However, when using this command inside a tabular environment which have a \footnotesize the value I receive is: ec-lmr8 instead of ec-lmr10

So I simply want latex to evaluate the command directly when used at the \newcommand line so don't store the pure command but storing the result. How is this possible?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\fontname` is a primitive TeX command that should be followed by a font specifier or by `\font` (that represents the current font).

On the other hand, TeX is a macro expansion language, so your definition of `\defaultfont` just replaces `\defaultfont` with `\fontname\font`, so it refers to the font current at the time the expansion is performed. You need to expand `\fontname` at the time of definition, rather than at call time.

If you want to store the name of the default font

```
\AtBeginDocument{\xdef\defaultfont{\fontname\font}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\AtBeginDocument{\xdef\defaultfont{\fontname\font}}

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm} % just for the example

\begin{document}

text\footnote{The default font is \defaultfont, not
the same as \fontname\font}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find that one can use \edef for a direct evaluation before passing the argument like

```
\edef\currentfont{\fontname\font}
```

But did not find something for \newcommand